# It is Wajib to reply "Salam-on-Alaikum"?

Tags: fiqh, greetings, wajib

It is considered as a famous issue that almost majority of people in my country (Iran) say that it is Wajib (compulsory) to reply the person who says Salam to you. 
I.e. if somebody tell you "a-Salamon-Alaikom", then it would be considered as a Wijib practice for you to tell him or her "Alaikum-aSSalam".

I was wondering if it is an Islamic rule. 
If so, is there any related Qur'anic verse or hadith (tradition) concerning it?

Comment: It has been narrated from Hazrat Ali May Allah be pleased with himthat the Holy Prophet Peace & Blessings Be Upon Himsaid, "Commonly in Islam there are six rights of a Muslim upon a Muslim: when he meets him he should give him salaam; when he invites him (to a meal) he should accept it; when he sneezes he should bless him; when he falls ill he should visit him; when he dies he should accompany his funeral and he should prefer for him that which he prefers for himself."

Comment: oops, it is an interesting hadith that you showed. actually these 6 items can  make the muslims' relationship stronger.So, it  also can demonstrate the significance of greetings to Muslims as well.

Answer (score 3):

> It is Wajib to reply “Salam-on-Alaikum”?

**Yes, it is Wajib (mandatory) to reply that. Actually, based on the narration:** **it is Mustahab (recommended) to start by Saying Salam, but it is Wajib to reply that.**

---

This narration is related to the following book:

> (Kolaini, muhammad ibn Yaqub, al-Kafi, volume 2, page 644 ...)  .
>   کلینی، محمد بن یعقوب، الکافی، محقق و مصحح: غفارى، على اکبر،  آخوندى،
>   محمد، ج ‏2، ص 644، دار الکتب الإسلامیة، تهران، چاپ چهارم 1407ق.

---

**Source:**

[www.islamquest.net](http://%20-%20http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa27283)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. It's even been narrated, that if one was to be praying, and someone walked in and said Salam, you are to answer mid-salat, then continue on praying.

Comment: Please consider adding evidences to support your claims and read [answer].